# using"psql -U postgres" ,it told me that "role postgres not exist"?

Tags: postgresql, psql

Before this problem come out,I have a port conflict in 5432.(it is because I install it from binary package which create a user "postgres" in my mac and this user start another postmaster. then I stop it)
solve the above problem,this come out.

I install this using default setting.

so how can I deal with it?

thank for your answer...

Answer (score 0):

Can you this way and tell me how it is working for you:

`sudo -u postgres psql`